# python bar chart displaying numbers instead of text

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a simple bar chart with matplotlib from a dataframe however numbers are being displayed on x axis instead of the text from the dataframe column

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
EI_levels = ["very low","low","medium","high","very high"]
#generate dataframe of values
EI = pd.DataFrame({'level': np.random.choice(EI_levels,p = [0.05, 0.05, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3],size=500)})
#generate contingency table of counts
EI_df = pd.DataFrame(EI.level.value_counts().reset_index())
EI_df.columns = ['level', 'count']
EI_df.set_index('level')
#Generate bar chart
ax = EI_df[['level', 'count']].plot(kind='bar', title ="Emotional Intelligence",figsize=(15, 10))
ax.xticks = (EI_df.level, ["very low","low","medium","high","very high"])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`ax.set_xticklabels()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) to set the tick labels to the text values.

```
ax = EI_df[['level', 'count']].plot(kind='bar', title ="Emotional Intelligence")
ax.set_xticklabels(EI_df.level)
plt.show()
```

Comment: How can I get the labels to match the actual count values? when I run your code It simply adds the labels to the x axis but does not link them to the values

Comment: @MattP - I've updated my answer. I misinterpreted your code and thought you wanted the labels as they were in the list. The code now puts the labels in the order they are in the `EI_df.level` column.